# How to insert JSON to an existing table without specifying column names?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2016

To a table with two columns, named `Id` and `Name`, how can I insert the following json as rows, but without explicitly specifying the column names of the table (i.e. without `WITH (Id ..., Name ...`)?

```json
[
    {
        "Id": "f08af9c2-8e67-4a7f-9413-1afffa2de96b",
        "SomeOtherKey": " ... ",
        "Name": "The One",
        ...
    },
    {
        "Name": "All is one"
        "Id": "9bbb094b-aa64-4c36-90a2-50e10f91c6a3",
        "Whatever": 99,
        ...
    },

    {       
        "Id": "af9d22d8-1e46-4d57-8179-75f094d2efa1",
        "SomeArrayWhyNot": [0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21]
        "Surprise": "This one does not have a Name value!!! "
        ...
    },

    ...
]
```

The question is basically how to make SQL match the key-name to its suitable column name, ignoring json values with keys that do not have suitable column names, resulting with the following table (for the above json example):

| Id | Name |
| --- | --- |
| f08af9c2-8e67-4a7f-9413-1afffa2de96b | The One |
| 9bbb094b-aa64-4c36-90a2-50e10f91c6a3 | All is one |
| af9d22d8-1e46-4d57-8179-75f094d2efa1 | `NULL` |
| ... | ... |

Comment: Which Database you are using ?

Comment: In Mysql we can do this using `JSON_EXTRACT` and `JSON_TABLE` functions.

In MS SQL Server we can achieve this using `JSON_QUERY` and `JSON_TABLE` functions.

Comment: @Tushar sorry, forgot to specify initially, it's SQL Server 2016

Comment: No Worries. I assumed it and started working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure why you want this, but you can also do this:

```sql
INSERT INTO YourTable (Id, Name)
SELECT JSON_VALUE(x.value, '$.Id'), JSON_VALUE(x.value, '$.Name')
FROM OPENJSON('[{
        "Id": "f08af9c2-8e67-4a7f-9413-1afffa2de96b",
        "SomeOtherKey": " ... ",
        "Name": "The One"
    },
    {
        "Name": "All is one",
        "Id": "9bbb094b-aa64-4c36-90a2-50e10f91c6a3",
        "Whatever": 99
    },
    {       
        "Id": "af9d22d8-1e46-4d57-8179-75f094d2efa1",
        "SomeArrayWhyNot": [0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21],
        "Surprise": "This one doesn''t have a Name value!!! "
    }]') x
```

EDIT dynamic version.
It has many caveats though, your column must match exactly the case in the json, it's very longwinded but if that's what floats your vessel...

```sql
declare @json nvarchar(max) = '[{
        "Id": "f08af9c2-8e67-4a7f-9413-1afffa2de96b",
        "SomeOtherKey": " ... ",
        "Name": "The One"
    },
    {
        "Name": "All is one",
        "Id": "9bbb094b-aa64-4c36-90a2-50e10f91c6a3",
        "Whatever": 99
    },
    {       
        "Id": "af9d22d8-1e46-4d57-8179-75f094d2efa1",
        "SomeArrayWhyNot": [0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21],
        "Surprise": "This one doesn''t have a Name value!!! "
    }]'

create table YourTable (Id nvarchar(100), Name NVARCHAR(MAX))
create table #cols (name sysname, row_id int identity)
insert into #cols (name)
  select STRING_ESCAPE(name, 'json')
  from sys.columns sc
  where sc.object_id = OBJECT_ID('YourTable')

DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max)

set @sql = N'
INSERT INTO YourTable ([COLS])
SELECT [JSONS]
FROM OPENJSON(@json) x'

SET @sql = REPLACE(@sql, '[COLS]', 
  STUFF((select ',' + QUOTENAME(name) from #cols order by row_id for xml Path(''), type).value('.', 'nvarchar(max)'), 1, 1, ''))

set @sql = replace(@sql, '[JSONS]', 
  stuff((SELECT ', JSON_VALUE(x.value, ''$."' + REPLACE(name,'''', '''''') + '"'')' 
    from #cols order by row_id for xml path(''), type).value('.', 'nvarchar(max)'), 1, 1, ''))
exec sp_executesql @sql, N'@json nvarchar(max)', @json = @json

select * FROM YourTable
```

Comment: Thanks! I'm trying to completely avoid column names, including the `Id` and the `Name` in `INSERT INTO YourTable (Id, Name)`, and the `$.Id` and the `$.Name` in the `JSON_VALUE` components

Comment: Okay, added a more dynamic version. do you know WHY you want this?

Comment: Perfect, thanks! need it to deserialize data into many tables, when incoming JSONs always match the tables' schema (but vary in order). Too many tables to write explicit deserialization dedicated for each table

Comment: That's fair i guess. I improved the query again a bit, in case you have weird columns with quotes

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [OPENJSON](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/openjson-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) function in SQL Server to parse the JSON data and then use INSERT INTO to insert the data into the table.

```
INSERT INTO YourTable (Id, Name)
SELECT *
FROM OPENJSON('[
    {
        "Id": "f08af9c2-8e67-4a7f-9413-1afffa2de96b",
        "SomeOtherKey": " ... ",
        "Name": "The One"
    },
    {
        "Name": "All is one",
        "Id": "9bbb094b-aa64-4c36-90a2-50e10f91c6a3",
        "Whatever": 99
    },
    {       
        "Id": "af9d22d8-1e46-4d57-8179-75f094d2efa1",
        "SomeArrayWhyNot": [0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21],
        "Surprise": "This one doesn\'t have a Name value!!! "
    }
]') WITH (Id nvarchar(50) '$.Id', Name nvarchar(50) '$.Name')
```

Comment: Thanks! but this one explicitly specify column names (`WITH (Id nvarchar(50) '$.Id', Name nvarchar(50) '$.Name')`) - that's exactly what I'm trying to avoid

Comment: I am not sure whether it's possible

Comment: The behavior of above query is : `SELECT * statement in the INSERT INTO` query is used to insert all the columns of the rowset into the table. The columns that do not match any of the column names in the `YourTable` will be ignored and you will get NULL values in those columns.

Comment: Can you try removing `(Id, Name)` and `WITH (Id nvarchar(50) '$.Id', Name nvarchar(50) '$.Name')` from the above query and let me know what error you get.
I can modify my query based on that

Comment: Basically running `SELECT * FROM OPENJSON('[ ... JSON ... ]') just puts all JSON records as values (e.g. `{ "Id":"f08...","SomeOtherKey":" ... ", ...`) in a column named `value`

Comment: Aha, OK. Thanks for letting me know. I will just try to find if it's really possible